# How do you solve this trig equation, I've tried what I know..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I solve this question?

$$2\sin{x} + \cos{x} = 0$$

I tried taking $\cos{x}$ from each side, and dividing through to make $-2\tan{ x }= 0$, but then I got stuck. I probably worked it out incorrectly, can someone please show me how to solve a question of this sort? Thank you in advance!

Comment: we get $-2\tan x=1\iff \tan x=-\frac12$

Comment: Omg, what an idiot, thank you, I saw what I did wrong.. wow, that mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the formula: $$a\cos x + b\sin x = \sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2\right)} \cos(x - y)$$
where $y = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac ba\right)$.

Using it, we get: $2\sin (x) + \cos (x) = \sqrt5\cos\left(x - \tan^{-1}(2)\right)$

Therefore: $\quad\boxed{\,\,\displaystyle x = 2n\pi \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2} + \tan^{-1}(2)\,\,}$

Comment: Clearly, he does not *have to*, but this answer is still useful.

Comment: @user2369284, don't you think its an overkill when $c=0$ in $a\cos x+b\sin x=c?$ We straightaway get $\tan x=-\frac ab$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It may be an overkill here, but probably teaches OP sth he can use on other problems.

Comment: I wasn't taught solving by formula, I just get the equation to it's simplest form and solve, is that a bad way to learn?

Comment: Yes ,I agree with you. But if acosx + bsinx had not been 0, then this formula would have come into use.

Comment: @SamirChahine It is not that complicated, see if you can prove it yourself :)